# Unable to access SSRS web URL outside Azure VM

Tags: configuration, ssrs, azure-vm, ssrs-2016

I've configured SSRS in SQL Server 2016 on Azure VM. However I am unable to access the web URL outside of the VM. Since it is my test box I've tried disabling the firewall as well. Still didn't help.

Any suggestions where to look? I've attached screenshot of my browser in my laptop.

The URL is accessible inside the VM where Report Server and Database Engine is Installed.

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL is wrong and also you can configure the firewall. Try below URL.  Configure port as describe below if you have not already.

```
http://jarvissqlvm.cloudapp.net/ReportServer/PageTo Connect to Remote Report Manager
```

Here are more detail steps.

Reference:

https://web.archive.org/web/20140523110804/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj992719.aspx

> If you want to connect to Report Manager on the virtual machine from a
>   remote computer, create a new virtual machine TCP Endpoint. By
>   default, the report server listens for HTTP requests on port 80. If
>   you configure the report server URLs to use a different port, you must
>   specify that port number in the following instructions. Create an
>   Endpoint for the Virtual Machine of TCP Port 80. For more information
>   see, the Virtual Machine Endpoints and Firewall Ports section in this
>   document.
>
> Open port 80 in the virtual machine’s firewall.
>
> Browse to report manager using Azure Virtual Machine DNS Name as the
>   server name in the URL. For example:
>
> Report manager:http://uebi.cloudapp.net/reportserver
>
> Report server:http://uebi.cloudapp.net/reports
>
> Configure a Firewall for Report Server Access
>   (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934283.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @sqlworldwide ! It worked, I just had to set up a Network Security Group (NSG) in Azure portal, make a inbound rule in the NSG for TCP port 80 and make a firewall rule in My VM.

Also, I used the DNS name to view the URL outside the server, In this case I used http://azuresqlvm.centralindia.cloudapp.azure.com/ReportServer